# using sed in perl

Tags: perl, sed

I have a file with the following entries

```
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shayam' Age='19' Project='Alwa'    
--ERROR---- Failed to process  
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='ram' Age='23' Project='Alwa'  
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='raja' Age='24' Project='Alwa'  
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shyla' Age='27' Project='Alwa'  
--ERROR---- Failed to process
```

I need to extract Name and Age from the corresponding line for which error occurred. In this case, I need to extract Name=shayam, Age=19 and Name=shyla Age=27.

Comment: isn't this the same as the other? just changing ERROR into INFO...?

Comment: yeah.. slightly same.. but in this case you 've to take Name and Age fields from the previous line. not in the current line..

Comment: Does it need the spaces at the end of each line?

Comment: Outside of the title, and the tags, I see no reference to sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick to the same approch of the other answer to the similar question, simply storing the last INFO found so far

```
$p = "";
while(<>) {
    if ( /^--INFO/ ) { $p = $_; next; }
    next if !/^--ERROR/;
    $p =~ /Name='([^']+)'\s+Age='([^']+)'/;
    print $1, "  ", $2, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi shin, its working.. sorry made one small mistake.. you are really kewl.. thanks a lot.. Need to appreciate your help..

Comment: Hi shin
 if the single quotes is not there in the Name feild, then its not working..

Comment: of course. the regex is built upon your sample output. you have to change it according to what you really have; e.g. in the previous sample (other question), you used ". If you can use both indifferently you can change ' with ['"] even though this is simplistic since allow for `'Name"` which usually is not correct

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the other answers here, just simplified a little:

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my ($name, $age);
while(<>) {
    ($name, $age) = ($1, $2) if /Name='?([\w]+)'?\s+Age='?([\d]+)'?/;
    print "$name, $age\n" if /^--ERROR--/;
}
```

Usage example:

```
perl extract.pl input.log
```

Comment: thanks mike.. this solution too worked.. you people in stactoverflow are really genius.

Comment: Hi Mike,
 if the single quotes is not there in the Name field, then its not working. How to modify the code?

Comment: @shayam: I've updated the code so that it should work with or without single quotes in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with:

```
$ echo "--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shayam' Age='19' Project='Alwa'
--ERROR---- Failed to process
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='ram' Age='23' Project='Alwa'
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='raja' Age='24' Project='Alwa'
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shyla' Age='27' Project='Alwa'
--ERROR---- Failed to process " | perl -ne '
    if (/^--INFO--/) {@line = split;}
    if (/^--ERROR--/) {print "$line[3] $line[4]\n";}'
```

which produces:

```
Name='shayam' Age='19'
Name='shyla' Age='27'
```

All it does is store the information from every `INFO` line and then print it out when you get an `ERROR` line.

You'll notice it still has the quotes around the values but, if you *really* want to get rid of those, use the (very simplistic) `proc.pl` script:

```
#!/bin/perl -w
while (<STDIN>) {
    if (/^--INFO--/) {
        @line = split;
    }
    if (/^--ERROR--/) {
        $l3 = $line[3];
        $l4 = $line[4];
        $l3 =~ s/'//g;
        $l4 =~ s/'//g;
        print "$l3 $l4\n";
    }
}
```

Running this with:

```
$ echo "--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shayam' Age='19' Project='Alwa'
--ERROR---- Failed to process
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='ram' Age='23' Project='Alwa'
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='raja' Age='24' Project='Alwa'
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shyla' Age='27' Project='Alwa'
--ERROR---- Failed to process " | ./proc.pl
```

gives:

```
Name=shayam Age=19
Name=shyla Age=27
```

You can use any input file or stream with that (for example):

```
cat file.txt | ./proc.pl
```

or:

```
./proc.pl <file.txt
```

Comment: how to include in perl script? I have the entries populated in one file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the title of this question.  If you're programming using Perl, you could use a regex to capture the information like so:

```
/Name='(.*?)' Age='(.*?)'/
```

The name will be in `$1` and the age will be in `$2`.

Comment: But it will extract all the Name and Age field. I need to extract only the previous line Name and Age field where the ERROR occured..

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sed -n "\$!N;/--ERROR----/{s/.*Name='\([^']*\)' Age='\([^']*\)'.*/Name=\1 Age=\2/p}" file
```

If you are using bash, you may have to disable history substitution:

```
set +H
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be one of the rare cases where `redo` is useful.

```
$ cat file.log
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shayam' Age='19' Project='Alwa'    
--ERROR---- Failed to process  
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='ram' Age='23' Project='Alwa'  
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='raja' Age='24' Project='Alwa'  
--INFO----- Command processing: Name='shyla' Age='27' Project='Alwa'  
--ERROR---- Failed to process

$ perl -lne \
  '/^--INFO.+\b(Name=.+? Age=.+?'\'')/&&index($_=<>,"--ERROR")?redo:print$1' \
  file.log
Name='shayam' Age='19'
Name='shyla' Age='27'
```

For `INFO` entries, grab the name and age. If the following line begins with `--ERROR`, print the recorded parameters, but if not, ratchet forward, checking whether the following line is an info entry.